# Using alphabet as counter in a loop

Tags: python, list, character

I am looking for the most efficient way to count the number of letters in a list. I need something like

```
word=[h e l l o]

for i in alphabet:
   for j in word:
      if j==i:
         ## do something
```

Where *alphabet* should be the **spanish** alphabet, that is the english alphabet including the special character *'ñ'*.

I have thought about creating a list of pairs in the form of [[a, 0], [b,1], ...] but I suppose there is a more efficient/clean way.

Comment: `word.count('ñ')` or better `Counter(word)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not actually a dupe as you want to filter to only count characters from a certain set, you can use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict to do the counting  and a set of allowed characters to filter by:

```
word = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

# create a set of the characters you want to count.
allowed = set(ascii_lowercase + 'ñ')

# use a Counter dict to get the counts, only counting chars that are in the allowed set.
counts = Counter(s for s in word if s in allowed)
```

If you actually just want the total sum:

```
total = sum(s in allowed for s in word)
```

Or using a functional approach:

```
total = sum(1 for _ in filter(allowed.__contains__, word))
```

Using  *filter* is going to be a bit faster for any approach:

```
In [31]: from collections import Counter
    ...: from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
    ...: from random import choice
    ...: 

In [32]: chars = [choice(digits+ascii_lowercase+'ñ') for _ in range(100000)]

In [33]: timeit Counter(s for s in chars if s in allowed)

100 loops, best of 3: 36.8 ms per loop


In [34]: timeit Counter(filter(allowed.__contains__, chars))
10 loops, best of 3: 31.7 ms per loop

In [35]: timeit sum(s in allowed for s in chars)
10 loops, best of 3: 35.4 ms per loop

In [36]: timeit sum(1 for _ in filter(allowed.__contains__, chars))

100 loops, best of 3: 32 ms per loop
```

If you want a case insensitive match, use *ascii_letters* and add `'ñÑ'`:

```
from string import ascii_letters

allowed = set(ascii_letters+ 'ñÑ')
```

Comment: I do not know Spanish. But based on what I got on internet, it has other characters as well apart from just `ñ`. Check [here](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/psu/spanish/)

Comment: @anonymous, *Where alphabet should be the spanish alphabet, that is the **english** alphabet including the special character 'ñ'.* That is exactly what  `ascii_lowercase + 'ñ'` is.

Comment: @anonymous If you are refering to the characters á é í ó ú ü, I am not considering those. If you are considering characters like 'ch' or 'll', these are no longer characters of the spanish alphabet.

Comment: This wouldn't work if `word` had capital letters in it  - `counts = Counter(s.lower() for s in word if s.lower() in allowed)` would catch this if needed (at least for the English alphabet)

Comment: @asingtoruin,  `map(str.lower, word)` or using `ascii_letters` would do it if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy:

```
import collections
print collections.Counter("señor")
```

This prints:

```
Counter({'s': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 1, '\xa4': 1, 'o': 1})
```